# Collectionview gives 1 pixcel extra specing

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have created collection view with 3 cell and my cell size is 106 in iphone 5s but collection view gives 1 pixel extra space between cell.

Comment: Please provide some code to help us help you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? No spacing?

Comment: Yes i want no spacing among cells. And i have given minimumInteritemSpacing = 0. But it gives me 1 pixcel extra space between the last 2 colums.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute you set is called `minimumInteritemSpacing`, so the actual value that is used can be larger than the specified number, that is only a minimum. If you want that space to be exact, make sure you coordinate that value with the `sectionInset` property.